# Want to store values in 2d list in python after parsing using class

Tags: python, arrays

input file is:

```
A B C D E
1 2 6 9 10
5 8 7 1 2
2 5 7 4 1
3 6 7 4 5
```

I would like to store the titles in an array & want to use 2d list to store values
by getting no of columns and append rows as per reading. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("input.txt") as file:
    lines = file.read().split("\n")

heading = lines[0]
contents = [l.split(" ") for l in lines[1:]]
```

Comment: thank you for reply but how to do using class?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What class?

Comment: by using python class & storing data using them

Comment: I'm sorry, I still have no idea what you mean. Which particular class are you trying to use? What have you tried so far?

Comment: class TitleValue:
    def __init__(self) :
        self.columnTitles = list()
        self.values = []

Comment: Modify your class definition to:
def __init__(self, titles=[], values=[]): 
    self.columnTitles=titles
    self.values = values

Then use my code above and initiate an object like:
myObject = TitleValue(heading, contents)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232913/discussion-between-mdinaker-and-learner).